# What is the leipzig convention for glossing nonce words?

Tags: morphology, interlinear-gloss

How do you gloss nonce words (words which are created for a single occasion and have no meaning on their own) in interlinear glossing?

Comment: I don’t think there is a specific rule for that. I would probably just write ‘ɴᴏɴᴄᴇ’ on its own. I don’t think that would be likely to be misunderstood.